# How do I crack a double encrypted Hash

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, hashing, decryption

I created a hash which is encrypted like this: `$What_i_made=BCrypt(MD5(Plain Text Password))` and I wonder if it can be cracked. Currently, I thought of two ways:

1. Brute force `$What_i_made` to get the MD5 Hash then do a dictionary attack on the MD5 Hash. However, this will take ages as Bcrypt is so slow and a MD5 is 32 characters long.
2. `$result=Bcrypt(MD5(random combination))` and compare `$result`to `$What_i_made`until they match. This will be much faster, but I am not really sure how to do this. I tried John and Hashcat but I am not really sure how you can do this with them, so I am turning to the community for help. Thanks. :)

BTW, any other tools that work will also do and I would prefer a method which allows for trying every single combinations instead of dictionary attaks.

Comment: Note that a hash isn't encryption; there is a double hash here, but no encryption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a password cracker, I encourage all of my targets to use this technique. ;)

It seems like a good idea, but it turns out that against real-world attacks, **wrapping an unsalted hash with bcrypt is demonstrably weaker than simply using bcrypt**.

This is because attackers can do this:

1. Acquire existing MD5 passwords - *even ones that haven't been cracked yet*
2. Run these MD5s as a wordlist against your `bcrypt(md5($pass))` corpus, to identify bcrypts with known MD5s
3. crack the MD5s **outside of bcrypt** at much higher speed

In other words, in many cases you can simply crack the inner hash first. And for a fast hash like MD5, that means that for any password that can be cracked *first*, bcrypt's resistance to brute-force attack is *dramatically* weakened.

(I can't take credit for the technique, known as "password shucking", but it's very effective - especially when users reuse passwords across multiple sites, and the attacker has access to leaked password data.)

Here's a more specific, single-user scenario:

- User jo@example.net has an account on Site B that uses bcrypt(md5($pass))
- Site B is compromised, and its password-hash lists is leaked online
- Attacker acquires the Site B leak
- Attacker does a fast run against the Site B dump and determines from testing that the site is using bcrypt(md5($pass))
- Attacker first checks to see if any other known leaks in their collection contain jo@example.net
- If so, and any of those other leaks use MD5, Attacker simply tries jo@example.net's other MD5s to see if Jo was reusing her password, and it's the one "inside" the bcrypt
- If Jo's MD5 is inside that bcrypt, Attacker can now attack that MD5 at massive speeds until they find a crack. Attacker now knows joe@example.net's original password on Site B

Now, imagine that Attacker wants to attack all 100,000 bcrypt hashes on Site B ... but Attacker also has access to *thousands* of other leaks:

- Attacker writes a script to check all MD5 leaks for email addresses that match Site B
- Attacker first tries the user-specific MD5s against each specific user's bcrypt from Site B. (This is a "correlation attack"). Attacker quickly cracks about 20% (which also removes their salts from the overall attack, increasing attack speed for the remaining hashes)
- Attacker next tries other *known* MD5s from common passwords, and similarly removes those bcrypts from the attack
- Attacker then tries other *unknown* MD5s from those leaks. If they find one, they can then attack those MD5 as direct MD5s (without involving bcrypt at all)

And yes, the attack can also be done directly - either by MD5'ing the candidate passwords yourself, or using a tool that natively supports `bcrypt(md5($pass))`, such as [MDXfind](https://hashes.org/mdxfind.php):

```
$ echo "password" | tee bcrypt-md5.dict 
password

$ echo -n 'password' | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99

$ htpasswd -bnBC 10 "" 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99 | tr -d ':\n' | tee bcrypt-md5.hash; echo 
$2y$10$JUbSRB0GQv.yKorqYdBaqeVYLtbZ/sRXdbPWt6u/6R3tqbaWTlQyW

$ mdxfind -h '^BCRYPTMD5$' -f bcrypt-md5.hash bcrypt-md5.dict 
Working on hash types: BCRYPTMD5 
Took 0.00 seconds to read hashes
Searching through 0 unique hashes from bcrypt-md5.hash
Searching through 1 unique BCRYPT hashes
Maximum hash chain depth is 0
Minimum hash length is 512 characters
Using 4 cores
BCRYPTMD5 $2y$10$JUbSRB0GQv.yKorqYdBaqeVYLtbZ/sRXdbPWt6u/6R3tqbaWTlQyW:password

Done - 1 threads caught
1 lines processed in 0 seconds
1.00 lines per second
0.07 seconds hashing, 2 total hash calculations
0.00M hashes per second (approx)
1 total files
1 BCRYPTMD5x01 hashes found
1 Total hashes found
```

Unfortunately (for the attacker ;) ), it looks like [John the Ripper "jumbo" edition](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper) doesn't support this algorithm using its dynamic syntax:

```
$ john --format=dynamic='bcrypt(md5($pass))' --test
Error: dynamic hash must start with md4/md5/sha1 and NOT a *_raw version. This expression one does not
```

But for a focused attacker, it's much more efficient to simply dig out those MD5s from your hashes, and then attack those MD5s at speeds of billions of candidates per second on GPU.

If you want to do something like this - for example, to work around bcrypt's 72-character maximum - use a per-plain salt, a site-wide pepper, or true encryption in the MD5 step.

Comment: Can you please ELI5 how do you "dig out MD5s from hashes"? My understanding is that you're assuming that MD5 can be cracked instantaneously, so MD5s effectively are plaintext passwords. I don't get how it's any weaker than plain bcrypt. Point #2 on your list should be just as slow as a dictionary attack against plain bcrypt, since you have to check every MD5 against every bcrypt (because salt).

Comment: @gronostaj Fair question - I've expanded my answer with more specifics.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. This technique lets you (relatively) quickly verify if a person is reusing password from another leaked DB that used just MD5. But it works only if that person reused their password and its MD5 was already leaked and associated with their account. So while it indeed makes cracking significantly faster, it doesn't put the person at any additional risk since the MD5 was already known, right?

Comment: It's not strictly limited to *individual* password reuse, nor to leaks alone.. If you can match *any* known MD5 - used by other users, in other datasets, etc. - then you can attack those MD5s outside of the bcrypt *even if that MD5 does not yet have a known plaintext*. If you make a pass through a large corpus and find 10,000 unknown MD5s inside the bcrypts, you can then crack those unknown MD5s at super high speeds - much faster than you could attack the equivalent unknown bcrypt.

Comment: Hi @Royce Williams, sorry for the late reply but I still do not really understand why bcrypt(md5($pass)) can be cracked faster than a pure bcrypt. Lets say I have a bcrypt(md5()) hash and I decided to do a correlation attack with some other dumps which has md5 hash:plain text password, won't it take the same amount of time to try the md5 hash in the bcrypt(md5()) hash I wanted to crack before retrieving the plaintext password as opposed to when I have a pure bcrypt hash, and I can just try the plaintext password from another dump in the Bcrypt hash I wanted to crack? Thank you.

Comment: Because *you don't have to crack the MD5 before trying it on the bcrypt.* Attacker grabs a pile of MD5s from another leak, and tries them on the bcrypts. If Attacker get any hits, they just try to crack MD5 at crazy speeds. If it's still not clear, I encourage you to actually play it out on paper for a few iterations until you see the difference.

Comment: Hmm, I am still not too sure about what you mean. If I use a pure bcrypt hash, attackers can crack the md5s they got from another leak at crazy speeds before trying them on my pure bcrypt hash. If they do so, won't the time taken be the same as what you mentioned above? Alternatively, if attackers get dehashed leaks and try them on the pure bcrypt, wouldn't it be faster than trying them on bcrypt(md5()) hashes? Thank you very much.                                                          (P. S Sorry if my qns sound dumb but I am no expertise in this area.)

Answer (score 6):

This composite hash has no benefit over plain bcrypt. It could be marginally weaker due to MD5 collisions, but I don't think one could actually exploit it to make this attack faster. Anyway, there's no reason to pre-hash passwords with MD5. Now, to the actual answer.

---

You approach #2 won't work because bcrypt uses integrated random salts. Hashing the same input twice will produce two different hashes because different salts will be generated.

The result of bcrypt is actually a data structure containing actual hash and salt. To verify if a password is correct, you have to extract original salt from original hash structure and use it to hash the password to be verified. If the resulting hash matches the original, the password is valid. This feature is usually provided by bcrypt implementations.

---

If you're going to perform a dictionary attack, simply pre-hash all entries in your dictionary with MD5 and then run a bcrypt dictionary attack with the dictionary of MD5s. Reversing MD5s for successfully cracked passwords will be very easy and I'm leaving it for you to figure out.

A basic brute-force attack where all combinations are tested is impractical against bcrypt and MD5 is irrelevant.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response, but I do not really understand why approach #2 won't work(sorry I am a newbie). Since I have the salt, why can't I BcryptWithSalt(MD5(all random combinations)) before comparing the result to my original hash. Thanks

Comment: You can, but if you're going to check all random inputs it's impractical as I wrote in my last paragraph thanks to bcrypt being slow. I assumed you simply wanted to hash MD5s with bcrypt again.

Comment: Ok, so I should get a dictionary list, MD5 hash it before Bcrypting the MD5 hashes with the salt I currently possess(which is the first 22 characters of the hash)?

Comment: Competent password cracking software will deal with structure of bcrypt hashes by itself, you don't have to worry about it. You just need to provide it with a dictionary of MD5 hashes.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help, and I have one last question: How does Bcrypt really work? When I googled, I found out that Bcrypt appends a salt behind the plain text password before hashing it, thus giving us a Bcrypt hash. What I do not understand is that since the salt is already encompassed within the last 31 characters of the hash, what is the first 22 characters(also referred to as salt on google) even for? Thanks.

Comment: That's not really bcrypt-specific, it's how salting works. Without salts if two passwords are identical, their hashes are identical too. If 1000 users share a password, attacker knows it immediately because there are 1000 identical hashes. Cracking this single hash opens up 1000 accounts. You can't force users to pick different passwords, but you can give each user a random string (a salt) which is appended to the password internally before hashing. This effectively makes hashes different. You need to store this salt in cleartext too because you have to append it to passwords to verify them.

Comment: So the Bcrypt algorithm on a server will append the base 64 salt(first 22 characters) to the start/end of the clear text password, bcrypt it, then compare with the real hash(the last 31 characters)?

Comment: Essentially yes. It's quite more complicated actually, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) has some nice pseudocode but you'll need some cryptography knowledge to understand all of it. But if you were to add salts to, say, MD5, your algorithm would work. Don't do this though, while salted MD5 is better than unsalted MD5, it's still insecure.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for your quick reply and informative response :)

Comment: There is one reason to use BCrypt(MD5(Password)).  If your system is currently using MD5(Password) and you want to switch to something secure, you can calculate BCrypt(MD5(Password)) for all your existing passwords without requiring users to change their passwords.